# -[_NSInlineData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e351cc0'

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to pull userID from my successfull login details.Below is my code`

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
      manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
      manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

      [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

      manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];


      NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"username\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}",self.usernameTextField.text,self.PswdTextField.text];
      NSDictionary *param=@{@"params":str};


      [manager POST:@"URL" parameters:param

            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSLog(@"responseobject=%@ success=%@",responseObject,operation.responseString);

                NSLog(@"success=%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"userinfo"]);
```

my O/P:

```
responseobject=<7b22636f 6465223a 302c2275 73657269 6e666f22 3a7b2269 64223a22 31373222 2c226669 7273746e 616d6522 3a224179 75736822 2c226c61 73746e61 6d65223a 22477570 7461222c 22757365 726e616d 65223a22 67757074 61222c22 75736572 656d6169 6c223a22 66686a6a 6473227d 2c226d65 73736167 65223a22 4c6f6769 6e205375 63636573 7366756c 6c79227d> success={"code":0,"userinfo":{"id":"172","firstname":"Ay","lastname":"ta","username":"ss","useremail":"email"},"message":"Login Successfully"}
```

But cant pull data from response object.Below crash occurs

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e351cc0'
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the line that says

```
manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

By default AFNetworking will parse your JSON for you. AFHTTPResponseSerializer will just give you an NSData object as responseObject

Comment: Thanks for that knowledge.It works.But still m unable to retrieve userid.  
                NSArray *info=[responseObject valueForKey:@"userinfo"];
                for (NSString *userid in info) {
                   self.profile.userID=[userid valueForKey:@"id"];
                }  still crash occur [<__NSCFString 0x796b5e90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'
What m doing wrong?correct me plzz

Comment: userid is a string (you've defined it as such in the 'for' declaration), but you're trying to access it like a dictionary